# How to add urllib.request to Heroku requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

My python code uses:

```
import traceback
import datetime
import time
import praw  # We use version 3.6.1
import string
import urllib.request 
import json
```

and when deploying my requirements.txt (in it's entirety) is:

```
praw==3.6.1
yahoo-finance==1.4.0
```

As I try to deploy to Heroku I get errors such as urllib.request cannot be found... so I tried adding `urllib.request` to my requirements but I still get build errors saying

*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib.request*
*No matching distribution found for urllib.request*

So how can I resolve this problem using **Heroku**?

---

**Update: Instead of using urllib I ended up using the `requests` library.**

My python (.py) code now uses:

```
 import traceback
 import datetime
 import time
 import praw  # We use version 3.6.1
 import string
 import requests
 import json
```

My requirements.txt file is:
`praw==3.6.1
 requests==2.13.0`

That was all that was required to get this requests library to load. I could not find a version number for urllib so I gave up on trying to add it to my requirements.txt and used this other library instead.

Answer (score 3):

urllib.request isn't the library, urllib is.

So even if you did `from urllib import request` it would work. 
Add 'urllib' to your requirements.txt

Comment: Thanks... that makes sense. Should I use a version number for urllib? If so where can I find the list of versions?

Comment: I changed my code to `import urllib` \n `from urllib import request` but I still get a error saying urllib was not found.

Comment: You don't need to specify the version. Make sure you install it first before using. Also please consider upvoting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: How do you install it?

Comment: In your `requirements.txt` file, just add `urllib` This will install the latest version automatically

Comment: @rodrigorf what worked for me was using the `requests` library instead and tweaking the code slightly. See my edit.